# Request lost in Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, aix, websphere-7

I am facing a strange problem on my production server which is having nearly half a million request per day. In the peak time it gets around 150 tps hardly. My problem is every thing works fine but some of request which have hit to our servlet as it is showing in the logs but not processing further. We are getting no error/exceptions in our application?server logs. Not able to figure out what actually is happening. These dead request count around 4-5 out around half a million request per day as I said earlier. These dead request showing up any time of the day (sometime on peak time and sometime when traffic is low).
I wont be able to help with logs, because there aren't any. Below code is the only proof that those dead requests have hit over application.

```
log.info("Remote host"+request.getRemoteHost());
log.info("Request URL :" + request.getRequestURL()+ "?" + request.getQueryString());
```

These two line is the only trace we got. Below which there are a number logs we are printing but request is not going further.

Server: AIX
Java: IBM 6
Server: WAS7
Node:2

"I don't know how to tag this question so I am tagging with all possible tag."
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: So, you get a log indicating the Servlet ran (and it must be from the Servlet, because that's Java based logging code); then ask us why your Servlet isn't getting hit? I'm going with non-specific bugs in your Servlet (I can't be specific, you didn't post the code).

Comment: these dead requests may just be web crawlers that have short timeouts and are therefore not worthy of your concern.

Comment: what is web crawlers, is it usually happens any how i can avoid it.

Comment: for example googlebot, spiders indexing the internet

Comment: Oh no, I forgot to tell that this server is blocked by firewall and hit we are getting is from our client network. One more thing is that our client is concerned about these requests, there is a mismatch between their and our request's count.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch actually those two line i have shared above there are two more logs line just after that, but they are not printing.

Comment: @azeeza I get it, the [actual bug](http://www.history.navy.mil/photos/images/h96000/h96566kc.htm) is likely between your "four" lines of logs.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I will update my question with those two lines. But I don't understand why around 500K request is passing successfully and and 4-5 request are not making through it. Also our operation team validated the request there is no parameter name and value size/type mismatch when comparing to successful request :(